# How to check the child td in Datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, itemtemplate

I have a Datalist. Following is the structure of the ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemTemplate>                                        
  <div id="driversGrid" runat="server" style="width:3500px;" >
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="3500px"> 
      <tr>
        <td id="Td1" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden;">
          <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" BackColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  /><br />
        </td>
        <td id="title" style="width:90px;text-align:center;">
          <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" BackColor="White" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'  /><br />
        </td>
        <td id="am0900" runat="server" style="width:90px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="am0915" runat="server" style="width:90px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="am0930" runat="server" style="width:90px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="am0945" runat="server" style="width:90px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="am1000" runat="server" style="width:90px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="am1015" runat="server" style="width:90px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="am1030" runat="server" style="width:90px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="am1045" runat="server" style="width:90px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="am1100" runat="server" style="width:90px;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>          
</ItemTemplate>
```

Now, at the itemdatabound event, I fetch multiple time (data) from the database in form 10:25 AM.

I manipulate each data and convert it to `am1030` (similar to one of the td ID in itemTemplate). Now I want to check each td in ItemTemplate and compare the `lblID` (i.e. the staff ID) to the ID in my variable and then compare the `tdID` to the manipulated data. If they match change the background color of the td.

In short, I want to check that if the `lblID` is 3 then get the td with ID `am1030` and change the background color.

**Needs to be done in C#.net.**

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop to iterate through the `e.Item.Controls` collection, like this -

```
foreach (Control c in e.Item.Controls)
{
    //if c is HtmlCell, then check the ID and change the color.
}
```